# How can I query dynamically injected light children in a custom Polymer web element?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am attempting to query the children of a custom element which uses a content tag as an injection point for its children.

```
<dom-module id="content-element">
  <template>

    <content id="content"></content>

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({

      [...],

      attached: function() {
        console.log(this.queryAllEffectiveChildren('div'));

        // console.log(this.children);
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Its parent generates an appropriate element and then appends it into the `content-element`.

```
<dom-module id="parent-element">
  <template>

    <content-element></content-element>

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({

      [...],

      ready: function() {
        var newEl = document.createElement('div');
        Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('content-element').appendChild(newEl);
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

When I inspect the DOM, the div will appear inside of the `content-element` as expected.  The problem is that when the `attached` method is executed, it returns an empty HTML collection. 
I know that the `content-element` has children though.  If I `console.log(this.children)` in the same `attached` method, I will get an HTML collection with the div in it.  I have also noticed that if I 'hard code' the div, querying the effective children will yield an HTML collection containing the div.

```
<content-element>
  <div></div>
</content-element>
```

The ability to query the effective children is important as the number of divs being appended will grow and I will need to be able to filter them by class.

```
this.queryAllEffectiveChildren('.red-divs-only');
```

This will not be possible using `this.children` as an HTML collection is not editable like an array.

### Update

If I add a public method called `addElement` to the `content-element`, which appends an element passed to it by the parent, I am able to get results with `queryAllEffectiveChildren()`.  However, I do not understand why this works and the other way does not.

```
<dom-module id="content-element">
  <template>

    <content id="content"></content>

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({

      [...],

      addElement: function(el) {
        Polymer.dom(this).appendChild(el);
      },

      attached: function() {
        console.log(this.queryAllEffectiveChildren('div'));
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="parent-element">
  <template>

    <content-element></content-element>

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({

      [...],

      ready: function() {
        var newEl = document.createElement('div');
        var conEl = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('content-element');

        conEl.addElement(newEl);
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this problem lies in where the children are being appended.

`Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('content-element')` is targeting the local root, which is not where the children should be appended for use with a content tag.

Instead one should follow the instructions laid out in the Polymer documentation for appending children to the light dom.  This can be done by passing a node to a public method where the element can append the node to itself:

```
addElement: function(el) {
  Polymer.dom(this).appendChild(el);
}
```

Also, the light DOM can be targeted directly:

```
var newEl = document.createElement('div');
var conEl = Polymer.dom(this.querySelector('content-element')).appendChild(newEl);
```

Following one of these methods will allow light DOM Polymer methods to interact properly with children of an element using a content tag.